# ax.bar shows other plot than df.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime-format

i want to plot a barchart with datetime on x-axis.
And i know that pd.plot(kind='bar) will plot the datetime as string category and matplotlib will plot as numerical values.
But why does't matplotlib display all bars like pd.plot?

```
index=pd.date_range('2007-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='MS')
values=np.arange(0,180)
s=pd.Series(values)
s.index=index


s.plot(kind='bar')
```

Plotted with `pd.plot`
[image]

```
plt.bar(s.index,s.values)
```

Plotted with `plt.bar`
[image]

edit:
same thing with only 15 bars:

```
index=pd.date_range('2007-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='Y')
index
values=np.arange(0,15)
#values
s=pd.Series(values)
s.index=index
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZp5l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCWkz.png)

Comment: Pandas bar plot is "categorical": it makes an x-axis with internal positions 0,1,2,... and then labels them with the index. If you don't want that, you can use matplotlib's bar plot.  Note that you have much too many bars to be plotted nicely. You can use `linewidth=0` to remove the surrounding white line in the matplotlib plot. A line plot might be more suitable for your data.

Comment: Just to follow up, the default width of a bar is 0.8 which for dates is 0.8 days.  With so many days on your plot, the bars are subpixel.  If you want a similar plot, plot as suggested above is good as is stairs ( if you want the flat plateaus)

Comment: Thank for your help, but if I set the daterange from days (many Bars) to Quartals (only a few bars) the problem still appears. Is there a other reason why matplotlib doesn't show all bars?